# where does drupal save images when you use cck and imagecache?

Tags: drupal, module, cck, image-caching

I am thinking in moving all JS and images from webserver to another server to mitigate the load on my webserver. then i will use **parallel** module to get this stuff from the other server.
now, currently i am using cck and imagecache modules. and i dont know where does drupal save the images.
i checked mysql (**files** table) and found something like this
**Mysql>select filepath from files limit 2;**
**sites/default/files/2010413132344592734_2.jpg**
**sites/default/files/2010491910913580_5.jpg**
i checked for such files but i didnt find anything like this in this directory!!
i inspected one of the images in one of my articles and found that this image is in one of the cache folders that have been generated automatically by imagecache module. i tried to delete this image from server and refreshed my page, imagecache recreated it.
now where did imagecach get this image from? where does drupal save my images??

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Check the following locations

```
[...]\htdocs\drupal\sites\default\files\field\image
[...]\htdocs\drupal\sites\default\files\styles\large\public\field\image
[...]\htdocs\drupal\sites\default\files\styles\medium\public\field\image
[...]\htdocs\drupal\sites\default\files\styles\thumbnail\public\field\image
```

where [...] is the location of the htdocs folder inside your webserver container.
If you are using xampp then it could be C:\xampp183\htdocs............

Hope this helps !

In the drupal database, check the table "file_managed" and the column "uri" (which gives the uri to access the file either local or remote).

You might find a value like below .. (ignore the jpg name , that is only for my setup)
public://field/image/8_mayurkotlikar_tigress5.jpg

This shows the location of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Imagecache takes source images from whatever path is set in the files table, which is generally sites/default/files, the directory you listed. Your imagecache directory was within that directory, right? I think your files are probably in that directory and you just missed them for some reason. Directory listing cached in your FTP client, maybe?

Comment: i dont find the images in the specified path, and the images are appear correctly without having any broken image... so i wonder if the images in the database, i checked for that, but this is not true!!

Answer (score 0):

For myself, it stores everything in the sites/default/files folder.

But, some settings to look at...

- The **File system path** setting, located at ?q=admin/settings/file-system
- The path settings for the particular field.  Open the settings for the particular field, and look in the **File path** setting in the **Path Settings** fieldset.

If those settings are different, your file may be somewhere else.  Otherwise, it's going to be in your sites/default/files folder.

Comment: what do you mean by "The path settings for the particular field"??
Thanks

Comment: If you go to the "Manage Fields" for the content type, and hit the "Edit" for the field, it gives you settings for that specific field.  From there, look in the Path Settings fieldset (it's probably collapsed), and then the "File Path" setting.

Comment: Also... what happens if you go to [your site]/sites/default/files/2010491910913580_5.jpg  ?  Anything show up?

Comment: Does your site use the Private file system?  If not, you can try this... go to the "Display Settings" for your content type, make sure the image field you are using is using the "Image linked to file" option for Teaser and Node.  Look at a node, and check the filepath for the image and/or link.